# Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

estoy tratando de hacer una redireccion a otra pagina pero al poner el nombre del valor del RequestMapping y levanto el sistema me sale un error de "Request method 'POST' not supported".

*Main Controller*

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/hello.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
         public ModelAndView helloPage() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Login Form - Database Authentication");
    model.addObject("message", "This page is for ROLE_ADMIN only!");
    model.setViewName("hello");

    return model;

}
```

*Login.jsp form*

```
       <form name='loginForm'
        action="<c:url value='/hello.do' />" method='POST'>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='username'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                    value="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" />
    </form>
```

*hello.jsp form*

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">

    <!-- For login user -->
    <c:url value="/logout" var="logoutUrl" />
    <form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" id="logoutForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" />
    </form>
    <script>
        function formSubmit() {
            document.getElementById("logoutForm").submit();
        }
    </script>

    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
        <h2>
            User : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} | <a
                href="javascript:formSubmit()"> Logout</a>
        </h2>
    </c:if><h1>hola admin</h1>

</sec:authorize>

    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
    <!-- For login user -->
    <c:url value="/logout" var="logoutUrl" />
    <form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" id="logoutForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" />
    </form>
    <script>
        function formSubmit() {
            document.getElementById("logoutForm").submit();
        }
    </script>

    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
        <h2>
            User : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} | <a
                href="javascript:formSubmit()"> Logout</a>
        </h2>
    </c:if><h1>hola USUARIO</h1>

</sec:authorize>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sin conocer spring-mvc, veo que en tu método `helloPage`, sobre `/hello.do` esperas un tipo de request `GET`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
         public ModelAndView helloPage() {
```

Y en tu form tienes llamada con POST:

```
<form name='loginForm'
        action="<c:url value='/hello.do' />" method='POST'>
```

Entiendo que el error vendrá por ahí y podría ser tan simple como cambiar a

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
             public ModelAndView helloPage() {
```

Al final, lo que Spring estará buscando es un método/clase que trate una petición sobre /hello.do y que sea de tipo POST, y tal como tienes tu código no existe ninguno.

Comment: tienes razon, no me habia fijado en eso.. lo probe con el POST y si hace la redireccion bien pero no me agarra el usuario correspondiente..